# Rancher show alerting but email is not received?

Tags: kubernetes, rancher, rancheros

I am using Rancher for Kubernetes deployment. I have setup alerts if pod are downs. If a pod is down then it shows alerting but email is never received. Kindly let me know what is the issue?

I have opened an issue on GitHub for same.
https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/20492

Comment: any one can help ?

Comment: does anyone know the solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per attached issue on [github](https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/20492)

Hello,
I have resolved this issue. I have checked log for alertmanager
AlertManager is found in CluserName ->System (DropDown) & there is AlertManager Pod.

My issue was i have added the Non TLS enabled SMTP credentials though rancher validated non TLS enabled credentials & sent Test email but looks like rancher required a TLS enabled SMTP Credentials.